# angular directive's content not rendered, unless you force page reflow manually

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I experience the following strange behavior in ui-bootstrap and angular 1.4. When I put a  `footable` table directive inside a customized bootstrap panel, called hpanel, the `footable` initially takes more place than the panel itself:

[image]

But if I resize the screen (e.g. by collapsing the Developer Tools panel here), the `footable` directive draws itself and fits within panel:

[image]

Importantly, I've experienced similar problems with `angular-c3` charts directives (they load incorrectly, exceeding the size of hpanel, but upon page resize behave fine), so it's probably not just a broken directive.

Have you seen anything similar?

**DETAILS:**

Below is an HTML template that represents the non-functional part of page. There we have an `hpanel` and within it a table with [angular-footable directive ^1.0.3](https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-footable), applied to it.

Here's the template (`toolList.html`):

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="hpanel">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-tools">
                        <a class="showhide"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        <a class="closebox"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    Available tools.
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm m-b-md" id="filter" placeholder="Search in table">
                    <table id="example1" class="footable table table-stripped toggle-arrow-tiny" data-page-size="8" data-filter=#filter>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th data-toggle="true">Id</th>
                            <th>Class</th>
                            <th>Label</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Owner</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Contributor</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Inputs</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Outputs</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Base command</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Arguments</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Requirements</th>
                            <th data-hide="all">Hints</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="tool in vm.tools">
                            <td><a ui-sref="tool-detail({id: tool.id})">{{tool.id}}</a></td>
                            <td>{{tool.tool_class}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.label}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.description}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.owner}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.contributor}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.baseCommand}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.arguments}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.requirements}}</td>
                            <td>{{tool.hints}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="5">
                                <ul class="pagination pull-right"></ul>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The footable directive is meant to hide some columns of the table and show them upon click on a table row. It also provides pagination. It doesn't seem to work upon page load, but when I resize the page and the size of screen crosses the media-type margin (so that from medium-size screen it becomes large screen in bootstrap css terms), pagination buttons appear and columns that are meant to be hidden are hidden.

Here's how I import the `footable` directive in my main module `app.js`:

```
require("footable/js/footable");
require("footable/js/footable.filter");
require("footable/js/footable.striping");
require("footable/js/footable.sort");
require("footable/js/footable.paginate");
require("footable/css/footable.core.css")
require("angular-footable");

angular.module("app", [
    ...,
    "ui.footable",
])
```

I use `webpack` to load all those modules and `bower` to install the dependencies.

hpanel is just a `scss` class, here is its definition:

```
/* Panels */
.hpanel > .panel-heading {
  color: inherit;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px 4px;
  transition: all .3s;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.hpanel .hbuilt.panel-heading {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.hpanel > .panel-footer, .hpanel > .panel-section {
  color: inherit;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-top: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  background: $color-bright;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}

.hpanel.panel-collapse > .panel-heading, .hpanel .hbuilt {
  background: #fff;
  border-color: $border-color;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.hpanel .panel-body {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  position: relative;
}


.hpanel.panel-group .panel-body:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid $border-color;
}

.hpanel.panel-group .panel-body {
  border-top: none;
}

.panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border: none;
}

.hpanel {
  background-color: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.panel-tools {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.hpanel .alert {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  border: 1px solid $border-color;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.panel-tools a {
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: lighten($color-text, 20%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hpanel.hgreen .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-green;
}

.hpanel.hblue .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-blue;
}

.hpanel.hyellow .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-yellow;
}

.hpanel.hviolet .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-violet;
}

.hpanel.horange .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-orange;
}

.hpanel.hred .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-red;
}

.hpanel.hreddeep .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-red-deep;
}

.hpanel.hnavyblue .panel-body {
  border-top: 2px solid $color-navy-blue;
}

.hpanel.hbggreen .panel-body {
  background: $color-green;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgblue .panel-body {
  background: $color-blue;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgyellow .panel-body {
  background: $color-yellow;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgviolet .panel-body {
  background: $color-violet;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgorange .panel-body {
  background: $color-orange;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgred .panel-body {
  background: $color-red;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgreddeep .panel-body {
  background: $color-red-deep;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.hpanel.hbgnavyblue .panel-body {
  background: $color-navy-blue;
  color: #fff;
  border:none;
}

.panel-group .panel-heading {
  background-color: $color-bright;
}

.small-header .hpanel {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.small-header {
  padding: 0 !important;
}

.small-header .panel-body {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0;
  //  background: $color-bright;
}

.panel-body h5, .panel-body h4 {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.small-header .panel-body h2 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0 0 0 0;
}

.small-header .panel-body small {
  color: lighten($color-text, 10%);
}

.hbreadcrumb {
  padding: 2px 0px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 11px;

  > li {
    display: inline-block;

    + li:before {
      padding: 0 5px;
      color: $color-navy-blue;
    }
  }

  > .active {
    color: lighten($color-text,20%);
  }
}

.wrapper {
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.hpanel.collapsed .panel-body, .hpanel.collapsed .panel-footer {
  display: none;
}

.hpanel.collapsed .fa.fa-chevron-up:before {
  content: "\f078";
}
.hpanel.collapsed .fa.fa-chevron-down:before {
  content: "\f077";
}

.hpanel.collapsed.panel-collapse .panel-body {
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 1px;
  border-color: $border-color;
  border-style: solid;
}

.hpanel.collapsed .hbuilt.panel-heading {
  border-bottom: 1px solid $border-color;
}

body.fullscreen-panel-mode {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.hpanel.fullscreen {
  z-index: 2030;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.hpanel.fullscreen .showhide {
  display: none;
}

.hpanel.fullscreen .panel-body {
  min-height: calc(100% - 77px);
}
```

Here's `tool.module.js` file, which animates the template:

```
import angular from "angular";

var ToolResource = require("workflow/tool/tool.service");

class ToolListController {
    // @ngInject
    constructor($location, $stateParams, $state, tools) {
        this.$location = $location;
        this.$state = $state;
        this.$stateParams = $stateParams;

        this.tools = tools;
    }
}

// @ngInject
function routesList($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state("tool-list", {
        url: "/tool",
        parent: "layout",
        templateUrl: "/app/workflow/tool/toolList.html",
        controller: "ToolListController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        data: {
            pageTitle: "Tool",
            pareDesc: "List of tools, available for workflow construction.",
        },
        resolve: {
            ToolResource: "ToolResource",
            tools: function(ToolResource) {
                return ToolResource.query().$promise;
            }
        }
    });
}

module.exports = angular.module("tool", [])
  .service('ToolResource', ToolResource)
  .controller('ToolListController', ToolListController)
  .config(routesList);
```

`tool.service.js`:

```
module.exports = function ToolResource($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/tool/:id', {id: '@id'});
}
```

**ANSWER:**
Community is awesome!

- 1.5 years ago this directive was created
- 12 days ago this bug was fixed [by Alexryan in his fork](https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-footable/commits/master)
- 10 days ago I posted this question on StackOverflow
- 8 days ago I placed a bounty on this question
- 7 days ago ziscloud approved pull request
- in the morning today the bounty expired and in the nick of time Walfrat found out that the bug was fixed

So, yes, it was a bug in the directive that made it draw itself before getting the data from server. With the bugfix I just added `load-when="vm.tools"` attribute to the directive and it works fine now.

Thank you, Alexryan, ziscloud, Walfrat and other commenters/answerers. StackOverflow and Github just made my day!

Comment: Screen shots don't provide enough information to help you, please show us some code.

Comment: @RobJ You are right. I added the relevant code and explanations. Please, let me know, if you find that some details are amiss.

Comment: you are loading tool data asynchronously, so initially the footable directive you are using does not know what is the width of the window, you may use $(window).resize() after you get data, may be in a setinterval, this solution i am providing may be a hack and this needs to be fixed in the footable directive,

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Wait, I return a promise from `resolve`, thus, according to ui-router documentation (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) controller won't be instantiated before data are fetched. Can state rendering begin without an instantiated controller?

Comment: Can you add implementation of ToolResource? Also have you checked what code is running first, by adding some console logs?

Comment: @MadhuRanjan Added `ToolResource` code. No, I've not tried to add `console.log`s yet. Should I put them in `link` function of the directive and controller's constructor and expect directive code to be executed prior to constructor's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using this directive ? https://github.com/ziscloud/angular-footable/blob/master/src/angular-footable.js. It's an homemade (meaning not done by the editor of the footable) directive so it can be not rightly implemented to works with Angularjs.

Looking at the code it seems that you have to use an attribute `load-when` if you want to delay the initialization of the grid even though you use the resolve attribute in your state, it can be worth to test it.`load-when` shall be an empty array at start an will trigger the load after the array won't be empty anymore, but the data binded won't be used for the initialization from what i saw.

Note : i wasn't able to set a proper plnkr myself, i don't know the version you're using (and with which jQuery version) and online links doesn't seems available.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Directive's version is 1.0.3, angular 1.4, jquery 2. Can you provide a basic primer of `load-when` usage, I'll add the details myself?

Comment: i think you can just bind `load-when` to `tools` in order to test. I don't know either footable or this directrive, i just checked the code

Comment: Sorry, I'm just not acquainted with `load-when` pattern in angular at all and I can't google-out what it is. Can you give any example of `load-when`?

Comment: it's in the code of the directive you're using... just add the `load-when="tools"` to your footable element. It's a custom attribute used by that directive.

Comment: Wow, you're right. The commit, which added `load-when` argument to the directive was written 12 days ago, I posted this question 10 days ago, I awarded bounty to it 8 days ago and pull request was approved 7 days ago. I just didn't have this argument in my local version of angular-footable and didn't get, what are you talking about. I uploaded the latest commit, used `load-when="vm.tools"` and the problem is gone. Thank you. Man, that's what I call nightly build!

Comment: ahahahah and i was just passing by and checked directive's code, you're definitively lucky.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are asynchronously loading data (as was mentioned in the comments) your html is rendered prior to it having any data in it. This means the directive may be fired too early (if it is attempting to adapt based on data). Typically, in this scenario, you'll want to throw an ng-if on the portion of your html that is dependent on the data loading (and show a loading gif or something in its place). You can either run the ng-if off of the data itself being defined, or maintain a separate boolean that you set once the promise is resolved.

Comment: Wait, I return a promise from `resolve`, thus, according to ui-router documentation (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) controller won't be instantiated before data are fetched. Can state rendering begin without an instantiated controller?